# Restarting a program within itself?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
from datetime import datetime
platenumber = input("Enter the license plate number:")
start = input("Press enter to start.")
starttime =(datetime.now())
stop = input("Press enter to stop.")
stoptime =(datetime.now())
dist1 = 0
dist2 = input("Enter the distance of the road in metres:")

time = ((stoptime - starttime).total_seconds())
print((time),"is the time in seconds.")
distance = int(dist2) - dist1
print((distance),"is the the distance in metres.")
speed = float(distance)//time
print((speed),"is the speed of the vehicle in m/s.")
```

I want to restart the program after using it so that I can check the speed of the vehicle more than one time.

Please help me finish the code so that I can restart the code with itself and check the speed of more than one vehicle.

Comment: help me with the code that can help the code to restart within itself like continuous loop

Comment: Why don't you just use a `while` loop?

Comment: *"give me the code"* - no, do your own GCSE coursework.

Comment: Having a program repeatedly restart itself is almost certainly the wrong approach. I recommend learning about loops.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while` loop.

```
while True:
    # Do your code
```

At the end:

```
    again = input("Do this again?")
    again = again.lower()
    if again.startswith('n'):
        break # Get out of the loop
```

Comment: it says break is outside of the loop

Comment: Do you put that entire thing inside the loop?

Comment: it says break outside loop

Comment: I'm not going to write the code for you! I'm willing to help you, but I'm not going to just *write* your entire program bottom to top.

Comment: merci pour votre aide

Comment: Mon ami, pourquoi est-ce que tu parles en francais? Faites votre part dans ce piece de travail.

Comment: i am sorry wht should i do pls i am desperate

Comment: I'll give you only 3 basic guidelines: import statements at the top of your script, Place your code in a `while True:` loop, and then at the end of your code (but still in the loop) place what I have told you to figure out if you want to do the entire program again.